# Submit single form to two actions with one button via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

In my below code you can see '$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']'  'ContactCreate.php' which are two actions I need my single form sent to. I'm not sure how I can get this too work.

Thank you all in advance

```
$(function() {
    $("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']'  'ContactCreate.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#message").html("sending...");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#message").hide();
                $("#response").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nest a 2nd `$.ajax()` inside the 1st `$.ajax() success: function(data) {}`, with the 2nd url

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097747/multiple-url-in-same-ajax-callis-this-possible

Answer (score 1):

You'll need 2 ajax calls. You can wait both to finish using [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) method and execute common logic in there

```
 $(function() {
    $("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#message").html("sending...");

        var formSerialized = $(this).serialize();

        var ajaxCall1 = $.post('$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']', formSerialized);
        var ajaxCall2 = $.post('ContactCreate.php', formSerialized);

        $.when( ajaxCall1, ajaxCall2).done(function (v1, v2) {
            $("#message").hide();
            // your logic when both ajax request finished   
        });     
    });
});
```

It's also uncertain if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will resolve to anything on Javascript, it will depends on where this code is placed.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, i've tried all of your codes however it seems that the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] action is overpowering the ContactCreate.php. The only action registering is the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. I've tried each action individually and they are both working fine. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it next to each other:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>' ,
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#message").html("sending...");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#response").html(data);
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url:  'ContactCreate.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#message").html("sending...");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#response").html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't know what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is

Comment: @Daan it is given by OP.

Comment: Or just put the ajax in a `function(url){...}` and call that. No need to repeat the same code.

Answer (score 0):

you must use JS analog of REQUEST_URI

```
var request_uri = location.pathname + location.search;
```

On your code -

```js
 $(function() {
                $("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: location.pathname + location.search+ 'ContactCreate.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $("#message").html("sending...");
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#message").hide();
                            $("#response").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```