# Efficiently load lots of PHP without affecting page load times

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode, minecraft

Here is the source code to a status page I made for a Minecraft server. As it currently stands it literally pings all 16 servers at once, and as you'd expect that leaves the page extremely slow and ruins the usefulness of it overall.

Could I see examples of how to efficiently load one server's status at a time? I'm assuming it would use Ajax or something. My ideal setup wouldn't even check the server status until the page is fully loaded. Afterwards it'll scan each server in order and show the status. Unfinished servers will say loading until it's their turn to be queried.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions. Tired of waiting 40 seconds for my page to load haha.

```
<title>AvengeTech / Network Status</title>
<?php
include "layout/_header.php";

# Lobbies

$query_JSON_19132          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19132/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19132  = $query_JSON_19132["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19132 = $query_JSON_19132["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19132 = $query_JSON_19132["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19132    = $query_JSON_19132["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19133          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19133/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19133  = $query_JSON_19133["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19133 = $query_JSON_19133["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19133 = $query_JSON_19133["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19133    = $query_JSON_19133["players"]["max"];

# Factions

$query_JSON_19120          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19120/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19120  = $query_JSON_19120["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19120 = $query_JSON_19120["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19120 = $query_JSON_19120["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19120    = $query_JSON_19120["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19121          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19121/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19121  = $query_JSON_19121["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19121 = $query_JSON_19121["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19121 = $query_JSON_19121["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19121    = $query_JSON_19121["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19122          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19122/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19122  = $query_JSON_19122["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19122 = $query_JSON_19122["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19122 = $query_JSON_19122["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19122    = $query_JSON_19122["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19134          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19134/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19134  = $query_JSON_19134["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19134 = $query_JSON_19134["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19134 = $query_JSON_19134["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19134    = $query_JSON_19134["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19135          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19135/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19135  = $query_JSON_19135["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19135 = $query_JSON_19135["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19135 = $query_JSON_19135["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19135    = $query_JSON_19135["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19136          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19136/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19136  = $query_JSON_19136["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19136 = $query_JSON_19136["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19136 = $query_JSON_19136["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19136    = $query_JSON_19136["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19137          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19137/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19137  = $query_JSON_19137["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19137 = $query_JSON_19137["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19137 = $query_JSON_19137["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19137    = $query_JSON_19137["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19138          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19138/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19138  = $query_JSON_19138["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19138 = $query_JSON_19138["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19138 = $query_JSON_19138["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19138    = $query_JSON_19138["players"]["max"];

# Gunwars

$query_JSON_19140          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19140/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19140  = $query_JSON_19140["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19140 = $query_JSON_19140["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19140 = $query_JSON_19140["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19140    = $query_JSON_19140["players"]["max"];

# PvP Biome

$query_JSON_19141          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19141/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19141  = $query_JSON_19141["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19141 = $query_JSON_19141["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19141 = $query_JSON_19141["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19141    = $query_JSON_19141["players"]["max"];

# KitPvP

$query_JSON_19142          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19142/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19142  = $query_JSON_19142["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19142 = $query_JSON_19142["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19142 = $query_JSON_19142["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19142    = $query_JSON_19142["players"]["max"];

# Prison

$query_JSON_19145          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19145/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19145  = $query_JSON_19145["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19145 = $query_JSON_19145["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19145 = $query_JSON_19145["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19145    = $query_JSON_19145["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19146          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19146/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19146  = $query_JSON_19146["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19146 = $query_JSON_19146["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19146 = $query_JSON_19146["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19146    = $query_JSON_19146["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19147          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19147/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19147  = $query_JSON_19147["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19147 = $query_JSON_19147["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19147 = $query_JSON_19147["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19147    = $query_JSON_19147["players"]["max"];

$query_JSON_19148          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19148/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19148  = $query_JSON_19148["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19148 = $query_JSON_19148["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19148 = $query_JSON_19148["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19148    = $query_JSON_19148["players"]["max"];
?>

<h1>Network Status</h1>
<hr>
<h3>Lobbies</h3>
<br>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style="font-weight:400;">Lobby</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19132</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19132 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19132/$query_MaxPlayers_19132</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19132 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Lobby 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19133</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19133 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19133/$query_MaxPlayers_19133</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19133 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<h3>Factions</h3>
<br>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Factions Cyan</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19120</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19120 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19120/$query_MaxPlayers_19120</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19120 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Factions Red</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19121</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19121 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19121/$query_MaxPlayers_19121</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19121 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Factions Green</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19122</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19122 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19122/$query_MaxPlayers_19122</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19122 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Factions Classic</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19134</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19134 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19134/$query_MaxPlayers_19134</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19134 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Factions Classic 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19135</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19135 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19135/$query_MaxPlayers_19135</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19135 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Factions Gold</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19136</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19136 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19136/$query_MaxPlayers_19136</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19136 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Factions Purple</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19137</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19137 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19137/$query_MaxPlayers_19137</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19137 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Factions Blue</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19138</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19138 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19138/$query_MaxPlayers_19138</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19138 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<h3>GunWars</h3>
<br>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>GunWars</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19140</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19140 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19140/$query_MaxPlayers_19140</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19140 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<h3>PvP Biome</h3>
<br>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>PvP Biome</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19141</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19141 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19141/$query_MaxPlayers_19141</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19141 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<h3>KitPvP</h3>
<br>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>KitPvP</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19142</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19142 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19142/$query_MaxPlayers_19142</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19142 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<h3>Prison</h3>
<br>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Prison A</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19145</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19145 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19145/$query_MaxPlayers_19145</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19145 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Prison B</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19146</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19146 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19146/$query_MaxPlayers_19146</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19146 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Prison C</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19147</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19147 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19147/$query_MaxPlayers_19147</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19147 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<div class='paper'>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p style='font-weight:400;'>Prison D</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <p>play.avengetech.net:19148</p>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19148 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p>$query_OnlinePlayers_19148/$query_MaxPlayers_19148</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>--/--</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <?php
if ($query_OnlineStatus_19148 == TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:#00aa00;'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i> Online</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p style='color:#aa0000;'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Unreachable</p>";
}
?>
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<?php
include "layout/_footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: You could do something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18097830/689579. You could save your server urls in a javascript array, then loop over them using the url in the function. Since `$.ajax()` is asynchronous by default, it will load your results as they become available, instead of holding up your entire page load.

Comment: Could you post an answer showing an example of how I would implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example -

Store the urls in a javascript object -

```
var urls = {19132 : "https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19132/mcpe",
            19133 : "https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19133/mcpe",
            ...
           };
```

Then have a function to do the ajax requests -

```
function mceAjax(id, URL_address){
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: URL_address,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
             if(data.status == TRUE) {
                 //put the id as the div id, so then you can use it in the selector
                 $('#'+id).html("<p>"+data.players.online+"/"+data.players.max+"</p>");
             }
             else {
                 $('#'+id).html("<p>--/--</p>");
             }
         }
     });
};
```

And to check each server you would loop over your js object -

```
$(function() { //when the page is loaded/ready
    for(var id in urls){ //loop over each url
        mceAjax(id, urls[id]); //execute the Ajax function
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX to fetch the information your looking for. If you want to stick with just PHP you could use a for loop and make it loop 16 times.

Change `if ($query_OnlineStatus_19132 == TRUE) {` with `if ($query_OnlineStatus_19132) {` == TRUE isn't necessary.

Here's how to Speed Up some of your PHP with a For Loop:

```
<?php

include("layout/_header.php");

# Lobbies

//This will do it for server 19132 and 19133 as the $i<2 makes the loop stop at 2 loops and the $i++ makes the value 19132 up by 1 each loop
for($i=19132;$i<2;$i++){
    ${"query_JSON_".$i}          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:".$i."/mcpe"), true);
    ${"query_OnlineStatus_".$i}  = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["status"];
    ${"query_ServerVersion_".$i} = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["version"];
    ${"query_OnlinePlayers_".$i} = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["players"]["online"];
    ${"query_MaxPlayers_".$i}    = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["players"]["max"];
}

# Factions

for($i=19120;$i<8;$i++){
    ${"query_JSON_".$i}          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:".$i."/mcpe"), true);
    ${"query_OnlineStatus_".$i}  = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["status"];
    ${"query_ServerVersion_".$i} = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["version"];
    ${"query_OnlinePlayers_".$i} = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["players"]["online"];
    ${"query_MaxPlayers_".$i}    = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["players"]["max"];
}

# Gunwars

$query_JSON_19140          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19140/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19140  = $query_JSON_19140["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19140 = $query_JSON_19140["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19140 = $query_JSON_19140["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19140    = $query_JSON_19140["players"]["max"];

# PvP Biome

$query_JSON_19141          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19141/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19141  = $query_JSON_19141["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19141 = $query_JSON_19141["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19141 = $query_JSON_19141["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19141    = $query_JSON_19141["players"]["max"];

# KitPvP

$query_JSON_19142          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:19142/mcpe"), true);
$query_OnlineStatus_19142  = $query_JSON_19142["status"];
$query_ServerVersion_19142 = $query_JSON_19142["version"];
$query_OnlinePlayers_19142 = $query_JSON_19142["players"]["online"];
$query_MaxPlayers_19142    = $query_JSON_19142["players"]["max"];

# Prison

for($i=19145;$i<4;$i++){
    ${"query_JSON_".$i}          = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://mcapi.ca/query/play.avengetech.net:".$i."/mcpe"), true);
    ${"query_OnlineStatus_".$i}  = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["status"];
    ${"query_ServerVersion_".$i} = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["version"];
    ${"query_OnlinePlayers_".$i} = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["players"]["online"];
    ${"query_MaxPlayers_".$i}    = ${"query_JSON_".$i}["players"]["max"];
}

?>
```

Comment: How will a loop speed up the php? It will shorten the code, but you still have the same number of `json_decode(file_get_contents(...), true);` being executed. Just because you do something in a loop, it does not shorten the execution time, just the redundant lines of code to make the file shorter/smaller.

Comment: @Sean it actually makes it a bit faster but not much that you would actually notice it. Do realize my answer isnt just about a Loop it was just advice.

Comment: Could somebody post an example of how to load with Ajax?

Comment: @DaltonEdwards StackOverflow isnt a site where we Spoon Feed you the code. I recommend you to Checkout [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Do note that it requires you to load the jQuery library before the script containing the $.ajax code.

Comment: "Could somebody post an EXAMPLE of how to load with Ajax?" I wasn't asking you to spoon feed me anything. I was simply asking for a nudge in the right direction and a little example. If you've got nothing helpful to say stop commenting.

Comment: @DaltonEdwards you are asking to be spponfed... You literally asked for an example yet you could just google "Ajax jQuery" first link...

Comment: @DaltonEdwards No problem... ¬.¬