# How can i pass value to multiple url using ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

```
> <script>
>         $(document).ready(function () {
>             $("#year").on("change", function () {
>                 var year_id = $("#year").val();
>                 $.ajax({
>                     url: "month.jsp",
>                     data: {year_id: year_id},
>                     method: "POST",//HTTP method.
>                     success: function (data)
>                     {
>                         $("#month_id").html(data);/
>                     }
>                 });
>                 
>                 
>                 
>             });
>         });
>     </script>
```

What i want here is i want to send same data to another jsp page including month.jsp. How can i do that?

Comment: By making another AJAX request.  If you're successfully making one AJAX request, what's stopping you from making another?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097747/multiple-url-in-same-ajax-callis-this-possible