# How to get AJAX to post to multiple PHP files?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an array variable in ajax that I'd like to transfer/post to two separate php files, fetch.php and index.php.  My script below works for capturing the dropdown selections on-change and posting it to fetch.php, but I would also like to use the selections that were captured and do something with it in index.php when the submit button is clicked. Is it possible to post this variable (autotypes) back to index.php, if so, how? Or do I need to approach it a different way?

index.php

```
<form id="filters" method="post">
   <select name="automobiles" id="automobiles">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="car">Car</option>
      <option value="suv">SUV</option>
      <option value="van">Minivan</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="search">
</form>
```

scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#automobiles').on('change', function(){
            var autoVal = $(this).val();
            if(autoVal){                
                $.ajax({
                    method:'POST',
                    url: "fetch.php",           
                    data:{autotypes:autoVal},               
                })              
                .done(function(data){
                    $("#results").html(data);       
                });
            } 
        });     
});
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$car = $_POST['autotypes'];
.
.
.
?>
```

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097747/multiple-url-in-same-ajax-callis-this-possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple url in same ajax call?is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097747/multiple-url-in-same-ajax-callis-this-possible)

Answer (score 0):

First I would add a `success` to your ajax call and at success submit the form from index.php;

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/fetch.php",
        success: function(data){
            $("#filters").submit();
        }
    });
```