# Combining two URLs in one ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to solve a problem with getting data from two URLs.
So, I have a code as you see,

I have one url in one ajax, but I need to have two urls in one ajax so I can get data from both in the same time.

In this *example*, as shown below, I have one url which is`"/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Projects"`, but I need to add another url which is `"/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/ProjectBaselines"` and get data simultaneously.

I hope you can help me, thank you.

```
$.ajax({
      url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Projects",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
          var dataResults = data.d.results;

          var listItemInfo = "";
          $.each(dataResults, function(key, value) {
                var pr = value.ProjectId;
                var nom = value.ProjectName;
```

Comment: You cannot have two urls in one ajax request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple url in same ajax call?is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097747/multiple-url-in-same-ajax-callis-this-possible)

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully know the API of $.ajax but you can't make 2 requests at 'the same time' with it.

What you can do is create 2 functions that will return these requests and using Promise.all() to resolve them https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```js
const req1 = () => $.ajax({ url: URL_NUMBER_ONE, ...otherOptions });
const req2 = () => $.ajax({ url: URL_NUMBER_TWO, ...otherOptions });

const resolveBoth = () => Promise.all([req1, req2])
     .then(([req1Response, req2Response]) => {
         //doStuffWithResponses
     })
```

There are a few gotchas with Promise.all, so I strongly suggest reading the docs