# Multiple URL http post request with Axios or any other method

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, axios, http-post

I am looking to post multiple url to my server using http post method, i can not seems to find a solution to that.

Is it possible to do that with  [Axios http client](https://github.com/axios/axios)  or just simply making an Http Post Call ?

**Axios Post request**

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'www.myurl.com',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",

 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer HkwWTBXekkrR0MybFlnUmc9');

  },
     success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

**AJAX call method that i have tried that fails**

> [Multiple url in same ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097747/multiple-url-in-same-ajax-callis-this-possible)

```
var urls = ["http://www.test.com/users/", "http://www.example.com/users/", "http://www.test.org/users/"]
$.each(urls, function(index, value) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: value,
                    type: "POST",
                   data: (
            answer_service: answer, expertise_service: expertise, email_service: email),
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 5YCwxCbWEvHIHO_nRvURIG5hP7s');
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Axios has an axios.all method which can handle multiple requests. (https://github.com/axios/axios)

```js
const urls = [
  "https://www.test.com/users/", 
  "https://www.example.com/users/", 
  "https://www.test.org/users/"
];
const generateRequests = () => urls.map( url => axios.get(url));

axios.all(generateRequests())
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // All requests are now complete
    console.log('done', acct, perms);
}));
```

Few more examples:

- https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-send-multiple-requests-using-axios
- https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter/blob/master/controllers/api.js#L37